# Assembly Illegal Indexing mode

Tags: assembly

I know that assembler is pretty plain language and many constructs from high level languages doesn't match its pattern. I use Tasm.

Just have a simple program, that iterate through "two" dimensional array:

```
.model flat
.386p
.stack 100h
.data
    rows EQU 5
    cols EQU 2
    matrix  DB      3,      9,      1,      0 
            DB      -3,     4,      2,      -2 
.code
;some preparing with segments 
    mov cx, rows ;outer loop count
    mov si , 0   ;outer loop index
    RowsLoop:
        push cx
        mov cx,cols ;inner loop
        mov di, 0 ;inner counter
        ColsLoop:
            mov al, matrix[si*cols+di]
            inc di
        loop ColsLoop
        pop cx
        inc si
    loop RowsLoop
    end
```

`mov al, matrix[si*cols+di]` - causes error illegal indexing mode, although if I count it by myself before accessing it works. Why can't I make some arithmetic operation inside brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's [16bit addressing](http://sandpile.org/x86/opc_rm16.htm) and it doesn't have any scaled indices. The only forms allowed are those listed in the table.

There are [scaled indices](http://www.sandpile.org/x86/opc_sib.htm) in [32 and 64bit addressing](http://www.sandpile.org/x86/opc_rm.htm), you can make use of 32bit addressing in 16bit code by referring to 32bit registers in the memory operand, the assembler will then emit an address size override. If you do that, be careful with the upper 16 bits of those registers (should be zero to avoid accidentally generating strange addresses) and it won't run on the 286 and earlier anymore (probably not really a concern these days).

But you don't really need that here, you can just add `cols` to `si` instead of incrementing it, then it doesn't need to be scaled anymore. That will also work with a number of columns that isn't 1, 2, 4 or 8, which scaled indexing is restricted to.